# cannot connect to samba share on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: samba, file-sharing

I tried to set up a samba server on Ubuntu 18.04 (running on an old machine).
I followed this tutorial:
https://linuxize.com/post/hot-to-install-and-configure-samba-on-ubuntu-18.04/

When trying to access the samba share on another machine running Ubuntu 20.04 via:

`$ smbclient //192.168.178.24/josh -U josh`

I get the following error:

*do_connect: Connection to 192.168.178.24 failed (Error NT_STATUS_HOST_UNRECHABLE)*

When trying to connect with macOS Catalina using Finder -> Go -> 'Connect to Server' via:

smb://192.168.178.24/share_smb/josh

I get the error:

*There was a problem connecting to the server "192.168.178.24".
The server may not exist or it is unavailable at this time. Check the server name or IP address, check your network connection and then try agin.*

**Comments:**

I was trying to set up a samba share using several other tutorials, but none of them worked for me. It seems pretty straight forward to get this running in default settings, but I does not work for me.

While surfing the web for answers I tried this command
`nautilus smb://192.168.178.24`
on the machine (running Ubuntu 18.04) where samba is installed. A window opened where I could log in with the user Josh and then access the share directory and drag and drop files.

When running
`sudo systemctl status smbd`, it is also telling me that samba is up and running

I tried running of the firewall via:
`sudo ufw disable`, but I could still not connect to the samba share.

I am able to ping the Ubuntu 18.04 machine and I am also able to ssh into this machine from both (other) Linux and macOS machines.

It seems to me that samba is running, but something is blocking it being accessed from other machines.

I ope you can help me set up the samba share on ubuntu 18.04 (or on Ubuntu in general)
Greatly appreciate your help!

Output of testparm -s:

```
(base) manuel@manuel-MS-7253:~$ testparm -s
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384)
WARNING: The "syslog" option is deprecated
Processing section "[printers]"
Processing section "[print$]"
Processing section "[users]"
Processing section "[josh]"
Loaded services file OK.
Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE

# Global parameters
[global]
    dns proxy = No
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    map to guest = Bad User
    max log size = 1000
    obey pam restrictions = Yes
    pam password change = Yes
    panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
    passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
    passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
    server role = standalone server
    server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
    syslog = 0
    unix password sync = Yes
    usershare allow guests = Yes
    idmap config * : backend = tdb


[printers]
    browseable = No
    comment = All Printers
    create mask = 0700
    path = /var/spool/samba
    printable = Yes


[print$]
    comment = Printer Drivers
    path = /var/lib/samba/printers


[users]
    force create mode = 0660
    force directory mode = 02770
    path = /samba/users
    read only = No
    valid users = @sambashare @sadmin


[josh]
    force create mode = 0660
    force directory mode = 02770
    path = /samba/josh
    read only = No
    valid users = josh @sadmin
```

Output of smbclient //192.168.178.24/josh -U josh -d3:

```
(base) manuel@manuel-mbair:~$ smbclient //192.168.178.24/josh -U josh -d3
lp_load_ex: refreshing parameters
Initialising global parameters
rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384)
Processing section "[global]"
added interface wlp3s0 ip=2001:16b8:46f6:dc00:4bd:1683:395f:cf7e bcast= netmask=ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff::
added interface wlp3s0 ip=2001:16b8:46f6:dc00:4cae:49b9:a843:1d3c bcast= netmask=ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff::
added interface wlp3s0 ip=192.168.178.25 bcast=192.168.178.255 netmask=255.255.255.0
Client started (version 4.11.6-Ubuntu).
Connecting to 192.168.178.24 at port 445
Connecting to 192.168.178.24 at port 139
do_connect: Connection to 192.168.178.24 failed (Error NT_STATUS_HOST_UNREACHABLE)
```

When typing

```
$ sudo ufw allow 'Samba'
```

I get the following message:
*Skipping adding existing rule
Skipping adding existing rule (v6)*

Comment: I meant the tutorial on: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-and-configure-samba-on-ubuntu-18-04/

Comment: I struggled with accessing my NAS on a similar basis. In fstab I included the following line after creating a mount point in directory /media: //192.168.1.117/share-name /media/mount-point/share-name cifs username=user-name,password=psw,rw,uid=1000,gid=500 and now it accesses it perfectly.

Comment: Assuming your ip address is correct edit smb.conf and remove or comment out `interfaces = 127.0.0.0/8 eth0` & `bind interfaces only = yes`. Then restart smbd.

Comment: I did that, but it still does not work and I get the same errors. Still thx Morbius1.

Comment: I think the only way to find out if this is a samba error or a network error is for you to add to your original question the output of this command: `testparm -s`

Comment: I added the output of testparm -s

Comment: Nothing wrong with any of that. May be a problem with the Linux permissions of the target folders, encryption, or .... You might want to run the smbclient command again in diagnostic mode for more clarity of the problem: `smbclient //192.168.178.24/josh -U josh -d3`

Comment: ok, I added the output to my question.

Comment: The target forlders should have the correct premissions set.

Comment: When typing $ sudo ufw allow 'Samba', I get the message: Skipping adding existing rule, Skipping adding existing rule (v6). Maybe the firewall is blocking access